# How to access the state of one component from the other?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my react-native application i have a input form component and a button component. I want to send the login information to my server when user presses the button but the data is present in the form component.

How can i access the state of the form from the button component.

Comment: Please add relevant code and show what you tried.

Comment: I am a newbie in react. I read some articles which stated to use a parent component but it will actually not be useful in my application structure.

Comment: I just need a high-level overview of what i should try. Merging the two components would solve my problem but it will be hard to read

Comment: You should create a parent component that acts as a state container that handles the logic for both of those components.  I don't understand how this would hinder your application structure.  Would you mind explaining how it would?

Comment: https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17

Comment: `this.state` is meant to be contained within a single component. You want to use something like `Redux` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smarter way to solve your problem is to expose an onclick property on the button component and feed it with the event attached to the form object. Send an AJAX request to the server and your problem is solved.

**Sample Button Component**

```
  import React from 'react';

  class PokePagerButton extends React.Component {
      render() {
          let {text, tooltip, onClick, currentPage, value, isVisible = true} = this.props;

          return(
              <button className={'poke-pager-button ' 
                                      + (currentPage === text ? ' active' : ' ')
                                      + (isVisible ? ' ' : ' hidden')}
                      onClick={onClick}
                      title={tooltip}
                      value={value}>{text}</button>
          );
      }
  }

  export default PokePagerButton;
```

**Sample Consumption**

```
 class PokeForm extends React.Component {
   onPagerButtonClick() {
       const request = await fetch ('/echo/json', {
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: { a: this.state.pokedata }
      });
   }
   render() {
      <PokepagerButton onClick={this.onPagerButtonClick} />
   }
 }
```